# Post to a users Facebook feed without pop-up dialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, facebook-graph-api

So using the Graph API from Facebook, it gives directions on how to post to a users news feed. They give this code to do it:

```
FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
            message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});
```

However, this opens a dialog window and let's the user modify the feed, and then click publish, etc. How can I post to a users Facebook feed (assuming they have logged in via my site and accepting the publish permission), WITHOUT using this pop-up dialog, and just have it post something when they perform an action on my site, without them knowing.

Is this possible, or does that dialog HAVE to appear everytime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want a dialog window, then don't use the FB.ui methods.  You would then just call the [graph API via the javascript sdk:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/).

If you have an authenticated user with the publish_stream permission, and want to publish a new story to their feed:

```
var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```